# Asp.net Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: asp.net

I get the error message below when i try to run this code :

```
Protected Sub gv_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
        Try
            If Not Session("Data") Is Nothing Then

                gv.DataSource = CType(Session("Data"), DataTable)
                gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
                gv.DataBind()

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception 
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Error :

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext& context)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.SerializationInvoke(Object target, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.ReadValueFromStream(BinaryReader reader)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.ReadValueFromStreamWithAssert()
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.DeserializeItem(String name, Boolean check)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.get_Item(String name)
   at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer.get_Item(String name)
   at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState.get_Item(String name)
   at gv_PageIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
```

I tried to google for the solution but i never had any luck. Please help?

Comment: Is that the full stack trace? Which line exactly is the exception being thrown from?

Comment: `Try... Catch ex As Exception` may be squashing the real exception, since all you do is catch the exception and then throw it away. Remove that and see what happens, or at least add some code to log the exception details to disk or somethig.

Comment: Same error message

Comment: It's complaining about this line : If Not Session("Data") Is Nothing Then

Answer (score 0):

The issue was session state on IIS. I changed it from 'State Server' to 'In progress'.